# Neo4j Paginated - undefined method 'total_pages' for

Tags: neo4j, will-paginate, neo4j.rb

I am using Neo4j database and my Author class is including ActiveNode.
I am looking to have the index with pagination.
Here are the controller and the index for Authors:

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /authors
  # GET /authors.json
  def index
    @page = params[:page] || 1
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || WillPaginate.per_page
    @query = Author.all.order("name")
    @authors = Neo4j::Paginated.create_from(@query, @page, @per_page)
  end
...
end

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Listing authors</h1>

  <ul><%= will_paginate @authors, class: "pagination-sm" %></ul>
  <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,40,80,100], @per_page.to_i), :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th colspan="3">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @authors.each do |author| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= author.name %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', author, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_author_path(author), class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', author, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>
  <div class="btn-toolbar">
    <%= link_to 'New Author', new_author_path, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to 'Books', books_path, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'btn btn-xs home-btn' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the error is: undefined method `total_pages' for #
Don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `will_paginate`, you need the [neo4j-will_paginate_redux gem](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-will_paginate_redux) and shouldn't use the `Neo4j::Paginated` class directly. That class is used for doing basic pagination. `will_paginate` expects a `WillPaginate::Collection` object.

Comment: Now I am getting undefined method `paginate' for #<Neo4j::ActiveNode::Query::QueryProxy:0x007ff51d489760>

Comment: No matter were I am adding require 'neo4j-will_paginate_redux' to the code. The Gemfile has the line gem 'neo4j-will_paginate_redux' and I executed bundle command after the addition. The gem is listed as installed.

Comment: ```def index
    @page = params[:page] || 1
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || WillPaginate.per_page
    @authors = Author.as(:a).paginate(:page => @page, :per_page => @per_page, return: :a, order: :name) 
  end```

Comment: ```
<ul><%= will_paginate @authors, class: "pagination-sm" %></ul>
  <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,40,80,100], @per_page.to_i), :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>
  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th colspan="3">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @authors.each do |author| %>
        <tr>
...
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: In the home.html.erb file I included this line:
require 'neo4j-will_paginate_redux'

Comment: It's hard to tell from reading code samples in comments, but putting `neo4j-will_paginate_redux` in your template means that your controller doesn't know about the `paginate` method. Move `require neo4j-will_paginate_redux` to `application.rb`, after `require 'neo4j/railtie'`.